# File not uploading

Tags: php, laravel

I was working on a project and was trying to develop a file uploading system for skins.
When I tried to upload my skin, I was given "Call to a member function storeAs() on null"

```
    public function uploadSkin(Request $request)
    {
        /* $request->validate([
            'skins' => 'required|mimes:png|max:1024',
        ]); */

        $storage_dir = storage_path('app/skins');

        $request->file('skins')->storeAs($storage_dir, Auth::user->name . '.png');

        return route('settings')->with('success', 'skin uploaded :)');

    }
```

Form code:

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/settings">
        @csrf
        <br/>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="skins" name="skins" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Is your file input named "skins"? Can you maybe also post the form/relevant fields in your question?

Comment: Please paste your form codes

Comment: Ok, added them.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store a file like an image or any kind of files you can use a code like this:

```
public function uploadSkin(Request $request){
    $image = $request->file('skins');
    if ($image != null) {
            $image->move('uploads/skins/', Auth::user()->name . $image->getClientOriginalExtension());
        }
    return route('settings')->with('success', 'skin uploaded :)');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To uppload a file there are various ways in the laravel but for now you can try this to simply move your file to your directory:

```
if($files= $request->file('skins')){  
   $files->move('uploads/skins/', Auth::user->name . '.png');
}
```

Comment: What is "this"? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: And **why** should that be tried? According to the question itself, `$request->file('skins')` is `NULL` on uploading a file